# For a finite measure $\mu$ and complex $f$, $f$ takes on an average value $\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_Efd\mu$ almost surely.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

The precise statement of the lemma is the following:

Let $\mu$ be a finite positive measure and $f \in \mathcal{L}^1(S,\Sigma, \mu)$, possibly complex valued. Define 
\begin{equation}
a_E = \frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_Efd\mu
\end{equation}
and $A = \{ a_E \mid E\in\Sigma, \mu(E) > 0\}$. Then, $\mu(\{f\notin \bar{A}\})=0$.

I have the proof in my lecture notes but I am confused about some parts:

We assume that $\mathbb{C} \setminus \bar{A}$ is not empty, so that $\mathbb{C}\setminus \bar{A}$ contains some closed ball $B$ with radius $r>0$ and center $c$. Thus $|c-a| > r$ for all $a\in \bar{A}$. It suffices to show that $E = f^{-1}(B)$ has measure zero as $\mathbb{C} \setminus \bar{A}$ is at most a countable union of such balls.

So far so good, here is where I get stuck. Suppose that $\mu(E) > 0$, then
\begin{equation}
|a_E - c| \leq \frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_E |f-c|d\mu \leq r.
\end{equation}
This is a contradiction but honestly, I do not understand how either of the above inequalities arise. Can someone please explain? Thanks!

Comment: $$\left|a_E-c\right|=\left|\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_E fd\mu-\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_Ed\mu\right|\leq \frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_E|f-c|d\mu.$$

Comment: @Surb Thanks, it is still not completely clear to me why $c = \frac{1}{\mu(E)} \int_E d\mu$...

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I wanted to say $c=\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_E cd\mu$.

Comment: @Surb Ah yes thanks that is totally obvious now! What about the second inequality? I am probably missing something obvious again. Also, feel free to adapt into an answer and I will accept if you are interested in fake internet points :)

Comment: $x \in E \implies f(x) \in B \implies |f(x)-c| \le r$, so $\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_E |f(x)-c|d\mu \le r$.